# Get foaf:interest of the user profile

Tags: android, sparql, foaf

I am currently building a music recommendation system. The first step I want to build a personal user profile using FOAF (friend of a friend), but when using SPARQL I can not get foaf: interest of the file is the user profile.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/">

<foaf:PersonalProfileDocument rdf:about="">
    <foaf:maker rdf:resource="#me"/>
    <foaf:primaryTopic rdf:resource="#me"/>
    <admin:generatorAgent    rdf:resource="http://www.ldodds.com/foaf/foaf-a-matic"/>
    <admin:errorReportsTo rdf:resource="mailto:leigh@ldodds.com"/>
</foaf:PersonalProfileDocument>

<foaf:Person rdf:ID="me">
    <foaf:name>Pham Hai</foaf:name>
    <foaf:title>Mr</foaf:title>
    <foaf:givenname>Pham</foaf:givenname>
    <foaf:family_name>Hai</foaf:family_name>
    <foaf:nick>HaiLeader</foaf:nick>
      <foaf:mbox_sha1sum>c900f594220ceebb386c02ad2e157cef0fb397b2</foaf:mbox_sha1sum>
    <foaf:homepage rdf:resource="http://facebook.com.vn"/>
    <foaf:depiction rdf:resource="http://cms.kienthuc.net.vn/zoom/1000/uploaded/manhtu/2016_03_17/hg/anh-noi-y-giuong-chieu-nong-bong-cua-hot-girl-sai-thanh.jpg"/>
    <foaf:phone rdf:resource="tel:0962354550"/>

    <foaf:interest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/"/>
</foaf:Person>
```

This is my query.

```
Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel(FILE_NAME);
    showLogAndToast(model.toString());
    String queryString =
            "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>     " +
            "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> " +
            "SELECT * WHERE { " +
            " ?p foaf:interest ?interest ." +
            "}";
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    try {
        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
        while (results.hasNext()){
            QuerySolution solution = results.nextSolution();
            showLogAndToast(solution.toString());
            //Literal name = solution.getLiteral("interest");
            //showLogAndToast(name.getString());
        }
    } finally {
        qexec.close();
    }
```

**EDIT**
I had fixed bugs. Before that I was mistaken in the SPARQL query.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Which API do you use? Which SPARQL query does not work? Please show the query.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've updated my query then.

Comment: So you solved your problem? Would the solution be useful for someone else, or was it not a problem with your query (as posted here)?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with Apache Jena 3.1.0.

Tested on the command line with

```
./sparql --data /tmp/so.rdf --query /tmp/so.query
```

Returns:

```
------------------------------------------------
| p             | interest                     |
================================================
| <foaf.rdf#me> | <http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/> |
------------------------------------------------
```

Your Java code look ok, so it's not clear

1. if the data was loaded correctly and -> call `System.out.println(model.size());`
2. if your log output is shown properly -> call `System.out.println(qs);`

In addition, the interest will be a resource, thus, don't call `qs.getLiteral("interest")` but `qs.getResource("interest")`

Comment: Thank you very much. I use androjena to develop applications on Android.
Also let me ask: I want to use xmlns: mo = "http://purl.org/ontology/mo/" to concretize the <foaf: interest> in my profile. But it looks androjena not support this. How do I create a user profile for the music?

Comment: What do you mean by "androjena not support this"?

Comment: Yes, I think androijena not support xmlns: mo = "purl.org/ontology/mo/";
So you have no way to use foaf: interest to build profiles for music applications use the data LOD ?

Comment: I don't get it. `xmlns: mo = "purl.org/ontology/mo/"` is just a namespace declaration in an RDF file. How should that relate to an API that allows to work on arbitrary RDF data? **What** means "support" in your context? What does not work? How to you recognize that whatever you mean does not work?

Comment: By the way, at least from the project page https://github.com/lencinhaus/androjena , it's totally outdated - last meaningful commit is 6 years old.

Comment: Thanks so much. So, now you know a library that supports semantic web on android? I was looking to try, but to no avail. We wish you to help.

Comment: @PhamHai if you have a new question, please use the "Ask Question" button to post a new question (link back to this question if it helps provide context). Don't use comments for followup questions or extended discussion - StackOverflow isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will ask a new question. Thanks so much.